# how to change full posts to excerpt on inner blog page WordPress

Tags: wordpress

in WordPress I have an inner page called "blog", and in settings->reading I have that page assigned as the page for blog posts.  I want that page to be excerpt instead of full posts.  In the theme page.php is used for the (page) loop for the Blog page, but that's overridden by the assignment of blogs posts to that page and I can't simply change "the_content" to "the_excerpt" in page.php to make this work.

I need some conditional tag code to this happen (or would that even work?) in page.php, or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The Wordpress template hierarchy diagram will help you out - [Wordpress Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview)

Your `page.php` template displays an individual page, it will not be generating the blog archive page you want to edit.  Depending on your theme that will either be `category.php`, `archive.php` or `index.php`.

Just change the relevant file to change the excerpt on your blog page.